# Exclude posts with set custom-field (meta) from search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a condition that sets a custom field (hide_search = yes) when some posts are used. I have done this successfully, but I now want these posts to not appear under search, or not be indexed.

This is the code that I've come across, but I can't get it to work with my intended functionality.

```
 /** Hide all posts that have the Custom Field hide_search=yes set */
function hide_posts( $query ) {

    
    // If a search query is done from a non-admin
    if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ){

        // Get all posts with meta value {key = hide_search && value = yes}
        // Identify their Post Category and set it to negative value

        // Set Category with ID to -ID
        $query->set( 'cat', -1 );
        return $query;
    }


    return $query;

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_posts' );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Open to other solutions, if they are better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've found the answer to my question
[here:](https://www.geekwire.com/devblog/excluding-certain-posts-wordpress-search-results-based-custom-field-values/)

The code mentioned in the article is this:

```
function exclude_nonadvertorial_search($query) {
  //only run for the main query and don't run on admin pages
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    //now check to see if you are on a search results page
    if ($query->is_search) {
      //get sponsor posts that are NOT advertorials, so we can exclude their IDs from search
      $args = array(
        //get posts of the custom post type sponsor_post
        'post_type' => 'sponsor_post',
        //get all posts
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        //return an array of post IDs
        'fields' => 'ids',
        //now check for posts that have a sponsor_post_type that is not 'advertorial'
        'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
            'key' => 'sponsor_post_type',
            'value' => 'advertorial',
            'compare' => '!='
          ),
          //some posts don't have a sponsor_post_type meta field set, so check for those too
          array(
          'key' => 'sponsor_post_type',
          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
          )
        )
      );
      //now get the posts
      $excluded_ids = get_posts($args);
      //add these post IDs to the 'post__not_in' query parameter
      $query->set('post__not_in', $excluded_ids);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_nonadvertorial_search');
```